# Converting sql to sql of h2 database

Tags: sql, h2

How to convert sql to accepter by h2 database?

```
alter table examination_order_details
    add column is_duplicated boolean default false;

alter table medical_certificate
    add column is_reissued boolean default false;

alter table medical_certificate
    add column correction boolean default false;


alter table medical_certificate
    add column harmful_factors character varying[];

alter table examination_order_details
    add column sd_position_id integer;

alter table examination_order_details_history
    add column sd_position_id integer;

alter table examination_order_details
    add constraint examination_order_details_sd_position_id_fkey
        foreign key (sd_position_id) references positions (id);

UPDATE public.examinations
    SET is_valid = false
    WHERE name_examination LIKE '%-23%'

create table dictionary_harmful_factors
(
    id                       integer primary key generated always as identity,
    name                     varchar not null,
    printable_on_certificate boolean default false
);


insert into dictionary_harmful_factors (name, printable_on_certificate)
VALUES ('praca na wysokości', true),
       ('praca w torach czynnych', true),
       ('praca przy monitorze ekranowym powyżej 4h', false),
       ('kierowanie sam. osobowym do 3,5 t', true),
       ('kierowanie sam. osobowym do 3,5 t z przewozem osób', true),
       ('akcja zima', false);
```

Comment: What happens when you try these statements?

Answer (score 0):

1. `character varying[]` needs to be replaced with more compliant with the SQL Standard `character varying array` (it isn't fully compliant, but H2 also doesn't require length for `varchar` data type).
2. `integer primary key generated always as identity` needs to be replaced with standard-compliant `integer generated always as identity primary key`.